# How to set object state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
this.state = { 
    user: null
}
```

If the user has a name property how would I set it knowing that `this.setState({user.name: 'Bob')` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.setState({ user: {...this.state.user, name: 'Bob'} });
```

Comment: if user has other properties along with `name`, will be delete all what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
const copy = {...this.state.user}
copy.name = 'Bob'
this.setState({ user: copy })
```

and if you don't want to override existing properties like say age do this

```
const copy = {...this.state.user}
copy.name = 'Bob'
this.setState({ user: { ...user, name: copy } })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for this like:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    user: { ...prevState.user, name: 'Bob' }
}))
```

For more info:

- [Using State Correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

user itself is probably an object so you can set the state of user to an object

```
this.setState({ user: { name: "bob" }})
```

or

```
this.state = { 
user: {
    name: "bob"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your state contains an object, then you can update the value of nested state using the javascript spread operator.
Other user parameters will not be affected.

```js
this.setState({
...this.state,
  user: {
   ...this.state.user,
   name:'Bob'
  }
})
```